# What are some easy / moderate day hikes in the Maloti-Drakensberg Park?

Tags: hiking, south-africa, lesotho

Looking for some information regarding suggested half day to day hikes in the Maloti-Drakensberg region, as most of the information I could find online regards longer multi day hikes or hikes with strenuous climbs.

Any suggestions for resources on this topic or specific recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The [Maloti Drakensberg Route](http://www.malotidrakensbergroute.com/) may fit with your needs.

> In support of sustainable tourism and job creation on the Maloti Drakensberg Route, the private sector (MDR) and government agencies (MDTP) entered into a joint collaborative effort which includes both the governments of South Africa and the Kingdom of Lesotho.
>
> [Hiking and Walking](http://www.malotidrakensbergroute.com/activities/hiking-and-walking/)
>
> The trails and footpaths that criss-cross the four regions of the MDR offer a range of hiking options for those who take pleasure in being immersed in the fragile diversity of the natural world. From day hikes and gentle walks to extreme expeditions, the allure of exploring towering peaks and tranquil valleys or taking a moment to swim in a clear mountain stream provides a perfect escape from the bustle of daily life. There are numerous places to find accommodation, as well as the choice of taking a guide along many of the routes, making this one of the best ways to fully experience the splendour of the MDR, at any time of year.

It goes on to provide a volume of information, including [maps](http://www.malotidrakensbergroute.com/maps/) that can be downloaded, and filtered by area, activities, attractions, and accommodations.